# Attempting to get dynamically generated classes to loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a script which is dynamically adding a class every time the user moves their mouse in/out of the box (whenever they do, it makes the box larger). I am hoping to make this process loop, so that the large box goes back to a small box. I have attempted to use a if statement to check if the box has the class of "large" then it will revert the class back to "small" in the hopes that the document would repeat itself. Didnt work. Can you suggest any way of achieving this using similar code? I would hope to get this to work with 4 separate classes. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cs31g61q/1/

```
var container=$("#container");
var box=$("#box");

box.mouseenter(function(){
    $('#box').removeClass("small");
    $('#box').addClass("medium");
});

box.mouseleave(function(){
    container.on("mouseenter", "#box", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("medium");
    $(this).addClass("large");
    });
});

<div id="container">
    <div id="box" class="small">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All of the classes need to be applied to `#box` only? What is the role of `#container` here?

Comment: the role of #container is for the .on() function. ive read that to check for dynamically added classes it is best to have a container of this sort (i understand that you can use body as well, but i will be adding on top of this code)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cs31g61q/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the below snippet produce your desired result?

***Snippet:***

```js
var box = $('#box');
var classes = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
var iterator = 0;

box.mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass(classes[iterator]);
    iterator += 1;
    iterator = iterator > classes.length - 1 ? 0 : iterator;
});
```

```css
.small {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #000;
}
.medium {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.large {
    width:400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="box" class="small"></div>
</div>
```

This is basically iterating through a set of classes, applying them one by one on every single time mouse enters `#box`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it does. I didnt even think about using an array, which would require so much less code (I knew the code I was writing was extra long). Thanks for the help will try and learn from it moving forward.

Comment: A question a little deeper than that, how would you accomplish this if you were dynamically adding classes to the array? Like after a mouse click or a color entry?

Comment: Dynamically adding classes to array so that these classes could then further be applied to elements? Don't you think you would always know before-hand which classes you will need to apply to elements and hence, your array is always pre-populated. Perhaps I am not understanding the question, elaborate more please.

Comment: I understand your point that I would know most of the classes beforehand, I was just trying to come up with a situation where, for whatever reason, classes could be generated by the user and added to the box - but then be recycled and stored later on in the array. While it has no practical purpose, I'm just trying to come up with exercises for myself where I have to use and understand the jQuery .on() function for more than one attribute of the same element at different times.

Comment: If you can come up with a jsFiddle demonstrating what you are trying to say, we can try and find a solution to it. Seems doable.

Comment: Okay, I will work on an example and see how far I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m3jahebd/).

Check your logic: you only need one event listener - it should respond to either mouseenter or mouseleave and cycle through the classes (small, medium, large).
Below is a very simple approach, as demonstrated in the Fiddle above.

```
// Set up the event listener: every mouseenter or mouseleave
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', "#box", function(){
    var currentClass = $('#box').attr("class");
    var newClass = ''; // TBD in switch statement.
    switch(currentClass) {
        case('small'):
            newClass = 'medium';
            break;
        case('medium'):
            newClass = 'large';
            break;
        case('large'):
        default:
            newClass = 'small';
            break;
    }
    // Remove the current class, add new one.
    $('#box').removeClass();
    $('#box').addClass(newClass);
});
```